# How to know if Locale/system is using 12 or 24 hours format?

Tags: javascript

How to know if Locale/system  is using 12 or 24 hours format in JavaScript without using any 3rd Party Libraries ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use toLocaleTimeString method.

```
let date = new Date();
date.toLocateTimeString()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Date()` constructor.

Check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ombL1tb3/)

Comment: Good try Andy but it also not working.

Comment: How you want the output to look?